# SQL server 2012 convert Multipolygon geometry to geography - GDA94 / MGA zone 55 coordinate reference system

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, sql-server, geography-data-type, geometry-data-type

Is there a way to convert geometry column value which has GDA94 / MGA zone 55 coordinate reference system into Geography value in SQL server 2012.
The layer is a multipolygon layer

We were having the WGS 84 system before and the below code was working fine

```
SELECT GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(ogr_geometry.STAsText(),4326).MakeValid() FROM TableA
```

But now the code is returning error

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 40
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.
```

Can someone explain this error?

Comment: It's not valid to just slap a 4326 SRID on projected coordinates and ask for a cast. The function you require is `ST_Transform`, which is not available from Microsoft, even in much more recent SQL Server releases. You will need to use a third-party tool to reproject the column contents.

Comment: @Vince - thanks for your comment. So I understand this cannot be done in sql server.  we are getting the data into sql server table from ".gdbtable" files using ogr2ogr.exe. I will need to try to project the geometry to WGS 84 before storing into the table..!